# Equivalence of limits $\lim\limits_{x\searrow 0}\lim\limits_{\xi\searrow x}g(x,\xi)=\lim\limits_{x\searrow 0}\lim\limits_{\xi\searrow 0}g(x,\xi)$?

Tags: limits, derivatives, proof-verification

In my book, there's this modified/restricted version of l'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim_{x \searrow 0} f(x)=0 ~~~\wedge~~~ \lim_{x  \searrow 0} f'(x)=:c\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\lim_{x  \searrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=c.$$

Despite the assertion "easy", I could only come up with this:

$$c:=\lim_{x  \searrow 0} f'(x)=\lim_{x  \searrow 0} \lim_{\xi  \searrow x}\frac{f(\xi)-f(x)}{\xi-x}\overset{?}{=}\lim_{x  \searrow 0} \lim_{\xi  \searrow 0}\frac{f(\xi)-f(x)}{\xi-x}=\lim_{x  \searrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$$
Is this allowed? I searched the Internet, but apparently this isn't a thing. I would be thankful for any hints regarding this or an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the order of limits is sometimes invalid. Instead, since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x)=c$, for all $\varepsilon$ there exists $u$ such that $c-\varepsilon <f'(x)<c+\varepsilon$ if $0<|x|<u$. Consider $0<|x|<|y|<u$. By the Mean Value theorem:
$$c-\varepsilon<\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(t)<c+\varepsilon$$
since $t\in (x,y)$. Let $x$ tend to $0$: $$c-\varepsilon\le \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=\frac{f(y)}{y}\le c+\epsilon$$
Thus if $0<|y|<u$, then $\left|\frac{f(y)}{y}-c\right|\le\varepsilon$, which means $\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(y)}{y}=c$.